# Windows 8 - Panoramic Themes

Tags: windows-8, desktop, themes, desktop-customization

I just downloaded the theme "Panoramas Europe" from the [Get More Themes Online](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/themes?ocid=w8_client_themes) selection on the control panel page

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Personalization

I downloaded the theme and unpacked it, It works fine for roughly five minutes then it begins quickly changing the background image every 2-3 seconds, I have attempted to change the interval as to when the background theme changes.

I know this is not a major issue but it is an annoying one and would appreciate any suggestions as to why this happens

**Question: Why do my panoramic backgrounds keep switching faster than intended?**

Edit:
It seems to happen with all panoramic themes 
I attempted to capture a GIF of the screens changing however it did not capture the entire screen.
It seems to happen randomly now, like start/stop different times
[Link Here](https://i.gyazo.com/3d1c3b4a5ffc82f049be24cf7fdb1f87.gif)

[Another, Better? Link](https://gyazo.com/9054eeec57a6d62c77895dfd27db6f86)

Comment: I'm on it! Hope I can solve it...

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the themepack? Maybe you corrupted it.

Comment: I will attempt to reinstall the theme pack, Thanks for trying @RookieTEC9 - **Update** I have deleted the theme and have dowloaded it again and reinstalled. Will keep an eye on it

Comment: This might explain how to set your own pace: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oqjgMwJsOI

Comment: I believe this is a known common problem with Windows.  Many other people have been having the same issue unfortunately I don't see an answer as of yet.  Microsoft has chimed in on this forum however no answer was found.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fcd0a02e-a12c-40e0-be9a-c8cfd5fd2ea3/desktop-background-slide-show-fast-cycling-issue?forum=w8itprogeneral

Comment: @Dale Thanks for the resource, good to know its not just me having this issue